# How to configure iOS MDM payload DNSSettings to stay active after device restart?

Tags: ios, configuration, dns, mdm, dns-over-https

We are using SimpleMDM to manage iPhones and iPads, and push a Custom Configuration Profile with [DNSSettings MDM payload](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/dnssettings)

This DNSSettings payload configures device to use a custom DNS server via HTTPS protocol.

These changes work until the device is restarted. After the restart we can see the profile with DNSSettings payload on the device in Settings > General > VPN, DNS, & Device Management. However, the device is no longer configured to use that custom DNS server, until we un-assign and re-assign the profile on the device.

How can we ensure that a config profile with DNSSettings MDM payload is active on the device even after device restart?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to get this to work as well, then I found buried in Apple's documentation that when the DNS Settings profile is installed via an MDM, it only works when connected to managed wifi networks.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/dnssettings

Comment: Thank you very much for this insight! I confirmed that DNSSettings works with a wifi payload